# Unknown sticky Problem after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, upgrade

1. few weeks ago we upgraded mysql server from 5.5 to 5.6
2. on 1st server few days ago (5May) I reboot mysql server , after this customer reported that some database data table not load to their site . (mostly phpfox - also few in other scripts) - also new data not submitted to database
3. I was reinstall mysql - disable cloudlinux - cagefs ... but problem not resolve. also rebuild php
4. after above , I move that database to remote-mysql-test-server with same Mysql version (5.6) and problem resolved. So I found this problem mysql related
5. yesterday in an other server like above (server B - that mysql upgraded from 5.5 - 5.6 few weeks ago) when mysql server restart , same problem occurred . for example when I answer ticket (WHMCS) , this date not submitted to ticket ... some clients can't update their site .

few website error like this :
SQL] [1364] Field 'stat_time' doesn't have a default value
STRING: INSERT INTO pn_statistics (`stat_name`,`stat_value`) VALUES ('Day-1394-02-24','0')

also in this server when I move database to remote-mysql-test-server this problem resolved.

6. I speak with few system admin and they can't find my issue .

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROBLEM

I think your problem stems from a change in sql_mode.

- [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) is blank in MySQL 5.5
- It is [not blank in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)

## SOLUTION

Run this command

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Then, add this to `my.cnf` to keep [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) blank should you restart mysqld

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ''
```

You do not need to restart mysqld since you set it globally

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Seems like it would be better to figure what was wrong with the data (or whatever) and fix _that_.  Turning off `sql_mode` may be "sweeping it under the rug".

Comment: Hello ... thanks ...you help me resolve this problem.
but putting new config to mysql config file not work and need run : SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''; after every restart.