# Set sql_mode “blank” after upgrading to MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, upgrade

After upgrading MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6, some our app face to problem and need set sql_mode to blank to solve this issue. I added `sql_mode = ''` to `my.cnf` but there was no effect on the mysql setting.

How do I keep the sql_mode blank ?

Comment: Bad idea - check out the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html). Some of those settings are important.

Comment: You get a +1 for this because many developers have been mystified by this. Thank you for posting this question about `sql_mode`.

Comment: I owe you an apology. I answered your earlier question (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/101504/877) but never gave you a thorough answer. I hope the answer to this helps.

Answer (score 8):

## PROLOGUE

Someone asked the same thing of me in my organization because everyone was using MySQL 5.5. All DB servers was upgraded over the past 8 months to MySQL 5.6. Some client applications were being affected by `sql_mode` change as well.

## ROOT CAUSE

I just found out why what you did does not work and the workaround is very simple.

According to [MySQL 5.5 Documentation, sql_mode default is a blank sting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode).

According to [MySQL 5.6 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode), sql_mode is default is

- blank string in MySQL 5.6.5 and back
- `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` in 5.6.6 and into GA

**OK, I hope you are sitting down.**

This is the lazy way Oracle implemented [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) in MySQL 5.6: There is an additional `my.cnf` file.

If you run

```
cat /usr/my.cnf
```

you will see the following

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

See line 28 ?

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

## SOLUTION

**STEP 01** : Comment out line 28 of `/usr/my.cnf`

```
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

**STEP 02** : Set [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) by hand

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

**THAT'S IT !!!**

## EPILOGUE

- `STEP 01` prevents restarts of mysqld from changing [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode).
- `STEP 02` sets [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) now, so restarting mysqld is not needed immediately

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: On 5.6.12, `sql_mode = ` seems give blank setting, whereas  no mention of `sql_mode` gives `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: 5.6.6 and 5.6.8 changed the defaults.  5.7.5 will change the default again.

Comment: I get a blank setting when using `sql_mode = ''`.

Answer (score 6):

With 5.7.13 (and possibly other 5.7 variants), the following trick works:

in `my.cnf`:

```
sql_mode=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
```

and restart the server. If you do not want to restart, you can just do:

```
set global sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'
```

then `mysqld` forgets all of its pedantic defaults and behaves like default-configured 5.5.