# MySQL 5.7.15 turn off strict mode

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqld

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I'm trying to configure my MYSQL instance to turn off some of the stricter settings currently I've done this:

```
   mysql> select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                         |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
```

## sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
```

mysqld restart. Then try to see what the global SQL mode is:

```
mysql> select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
        +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        | @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                         |
        +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
```

Anyone any ideas on what to try next. Can't seem to get this setting to stick permanently and can't see any other files to try.

Edit:
locate returns:

```
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
```

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Comment: Please specify what version of MySQL. Is it MySQL 5.7, 5.6, or 5.5 ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - done. added a --version

Comment: Don't turn off only_full_group_by ! Fix your queries that are returning incorrect results

Comment: Please run `ls -l /usr/my.cnf`. Does that file exist ???

Comment: ls -l /usr/my.cnf returns No such file or directory. @Philᵀᴹ full_group_by is likely fine its a no_default_value thing I'm trying to fix but the code base is old so Im replicating a previous server config tht works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `Aug 05, 2015`, I answered the post [Set sql_mode “blank” after upgrading to MySQL 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109053/set-sql-mode-blank-after-upgrading-to-mysql-5-6/109103#109103)

In my answer, I explained how Oracle created an additional `my.cnf` called `/usr/my/cnf`.

It has this (keep in mind this is MySQL 5.6 I am answering back then)

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I guess some developer just gave up putting it in the code and slapped up a configure file as some demented shortcut.

If you have such a file, please comment out the last line and restart mysqld.

[MySQL 5.7's default value for `sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) is as mentioned

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY STRICT_TRANS_TABLES NO_ZERO_IN_DATE NO_ZERO_DATE ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

## UPDATE 2017-04-27 17:23 EDT

I just ran `mysqld --help --verbose | head -13` and got this

```
$ mysqld --help --verbose | head -13
2017-04-27T21:17:13.237941Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-04-27T21:17:13.238060Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_connections: 214 (requested 500)
2017-04-27T21:17:13.238065Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 400 (requested 2048)
mysqld  Ver 5.7.17-log for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Starts the MySQL database server.

Usage: mysqld [OPTIONS]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Please run `mysqld --help --verbose 2>/dev/null | head -13 | tail -1`

Check every file mentioned

## UPDATE 2017-04-29 19:03 EDT

The `/usr/my.cnf` trick I mentioned in [Set sql_mode “blank” after upgrading to MySQL 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109053/set-sql-mode-blank-after-upgrading-to-mysql-5-6/109103#109103) comes from a [post written by Morgan Tocker under the heading "Changes in MySQL 5.6"](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/01/14/making-strict-sql_mode-the-default.html). This bait-and-switch method for [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) may not apply in this case since this is MySQL 5.7.

As I mentioned in [my earlier comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172211/mysql-5-7-15-turn-off-strict-mode/172212#comment333019_172212), I have successfully [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) by adding this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=''
```

You should not have to restart mysqld. You login to mysql and run

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

This will set incoming connections to a blank [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode)

This will not change the [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) of currently established connections.

Restarting mysqld will guarantee the all incoming connections will have it blank.

If you cannot restart mysqld, you must restart your app/web servers and make them disconnect. Then,m restart your app/web servers to establish connections.

Please try this and let us the results.

Comment: I stumbled upon your answer after a Google. Unfortunately I have no such file.

Comment: Please run `locate my.cnf` and `locate .my.cnf` to scan the entire DB Server. See if there is another `my.cnf` or .`my.cnf`. My guess is that there is yet another `my.cnf` present.

Comment: updated question with results. I've had a look through those and no obvious over-riding setting :(

Comment: Also, if the default setting is the same as the docs..would that suggest the .cnf files not being picked up at all?

Comment: I have a VM with MySQL 5.7.17 as shown in my answer. The VM originally had 5.7.12 puppet-deployed with a manual upgrade to 5.7.17. I had this workaround in place since the MySQL 5.6 era at my job. I have it coded in puppet/hiera to create a `/usr/my.cnf` with the exact same contents I just showed you (including the last line commented out). I also have `sql_mode=''` using single quotes not double quotes. On my 5.7.17 VM I have sql_mode set to an empty string. This worked for me. Please try making a blank `/usr/my.cnf` and using `sql_mode=''` (single quotes)

Comment: I've created a blank /usr/my.cnf and added the settings .. still no dice. There are files in conf.d that I think are potentially being pulled in so looking at that next. Strangely a locate does not pickup the file in /usr/my.cnf although I can see it on disk.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - a separate search for `.my.cnf` is unnecessary. 
 From `man locate`:  "If any PATTERN contains  no globbing characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were `*PATTERN*`."

Comment: Hey @RickJames if Oracle (still does not roll off the tongue yet, Yuck) got rid of `/usr/my.cnf` as the hack for `sql_mode`, then maybe there is a new mystery afoot. I gonna look around the bug lists and see if sql_mode issues are still current.

Comment: There could be another file "included" by my.cnf.

Comment: `sql_mode` shows up in changelogs for 5.7.2, .6, .7, .8

Comment: And in changelogs for 5.6.6, .8, .10, .13, .17.  .6 changed the default from empty string to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.